# Non-Normal distribution

Tags: distributions

I have a dataset which is non-normal(relatively) with kurtosis 8 and skewness of 3. But when I took the log transformation of the dataset I found that kurtosis and skewness are now 0.9 and 0.3 respectively.

I am not able to understand the statistical consequences that it would have on my results ?

By results I mean results of various tests such as linear regression , t-test , anova etc ?

By transforming the data am I hampering the characteristics that the data inherently has ?

[image]

Comment: This question might be too broad to be answerable.  *Of course* you are *changing* the characteristics of the data when you transform them.  This is always done with a purpose within the context of a particular analysis.  An adequate account of all the possible purposes, contexts, and analyses would (and has) required entire books.  Could you explain what your actual statistical problem is?

Comment: I am working on a multiple linear regression problem where the dependent variable is "total cost to a hospital in curing patients" and independent variables are demographics(weight,height,age) , clinical variables such as patient history of illness , bp ,pulse etc .

Comment: Thank you--but what problem are you attempting to solve with a transformation and which of those data are you transforming?

Comment: I am only transforming Total cost and not the independent variables .

Comment: And why are you thinking of doing that?

Comment: Some people think that variables need to have something like normal distributions before you can do regression. That's wrong.  The distributions of your independent and dependent variables don't matter by themselves. What matters for multiple linear regression is having the outcome variable be linearly related to the predictors, with well behaved residuals. Transformations that achieve such a linear relation are what matters.

Comment: EdM, What if we get a well behaved result when we do the transformation and not without it ? Can this result be then used for the population ?

Comment: Yes. For a log-transformed predictor, the regression coefficient would be the change in dependent variable per _fractional_ change in that predictor.

Comment: Something like normality will be relevant if you're using the usual hypothesis tests, confidence intervals or prediction intervals, but it doesn't apply to the raw variable; but you don't have to use those.

Answer (score 0):

Taking logarithms of variables such as weight, height etc. renders these into a proportional error format and in prior work was shown to improve regression analysis in [similar circumstances](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6707938_An_improved_method_for_determining_renal_sufficiency_using_volume_of_distribution_and_weight_from_bolus_Tc-99m-DTPA_two_blood_sample_paediatric_data). Reading that link in its entirety will offer fairly complete information as to which tests should be performed and how to do those tests. Briefly, taking logarithms changes the variable format from additive to multiplicative, and since $\ln Y= a_0+a_1 \ln A + a_2 \ln W+a_3\ln H+++$ is the fit equation, then the final equation is $Y=a_0 A^{a_1}W^{a_2}H^{a_3}...$ Any further questions, ask them here.

In general, the characteristics of the data have to be tested to know which transformation(s) work best, and typically plotting helps as well. For example, linearity may improve or worsen, correlation may improve or worsen, residuals e.g., sum squared) may improve or worsen, heteroscedasticity may improve or worsen. Sometimes, an exhaustive list of [data transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation_(statistics)) must be tried.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am only transforming the independent variable and not the dependent ones so the above equation would not be valid here . Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Then $Y=a_0+ a_1 \ln A + a_2 \ln W+a_3\ln H+++$. Similar problem. Suggest you read the paper.

Comment: Aadish, that comment directly contradicts comments you have posted to your question!  You have told us you are *not* transforming the independent variables and now you state you are *only* transforming the "independent variable."

Comment: Whuber,Sorry for miscommunication I am only transforming the independent variable because it only had skewness and kurtosis unusually large than other variables .

Comment: You are saying "the" independent variable, and that there is only one. For $y=mx+b$, there is one independent variable; $x$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe show us some data. Playing a guessing game isn't working so well here.

Comment: Carl, I have uploaded a part of my dataset . Total cost and Log transformation can be seen as the two rightmost columns . Hope it helps !

Comment: Sill guessing what you are doing. Are you regressing the other parameters as predictors of ln(cost) perhaps?